# Get selected answer from foreach generated drop down

Tags: php, forms, foreach

I'm using foreach to generate a drop down and I want to be able to push the selected question to the database.

```html
<select name="secQuestions" id="secQuestions">
  <?php
  foreach ($securityQuestions as $secQuestion) {
    if($secQuestion['Question'] == $userQuestion) {
      echo "<option selected value=".$secQuestion['ID'].">".$secQuestion['Question']."</option>";
    } else {
      echo "<option value=".$secQuestion['ID'].">".$secQuestion['Question']."</option>";
    }
  }
?>
</select>
```

But $_POST['secQuestions'] seems to return nothing. What's the best way to get the selected question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: does your form have `method="post"` in the form tag?

Comment: Also it's good form to quote your `values`, like `echo "<option value='".$secQuestion['ID']."'>".$secQuestion['Question']."</option>";`

Comment: @Kinglish Yes the from has method="post"